# outlook event newMail (newItem)

Tags: vba, events, outlook, outlook-2003

I'm working with outlook 2003

I search a way to get the event when a new mail is created (when the window of new mail is created)

Note: I search every way to add a menu to new mail window)

Comment: if you think theres no way to do it, you can tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sample code should be placed in the ThisOutlookSession module. Restart Outlook and whenever you create a new email you will see the message box.

```
Private WithEvents objinspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set objinspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub objinspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
  If TypeName(Inspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
    MsgBox "newinspector"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: tank you. I had succeed with a dummy mail, I will check your code

Dim outl As Object
    Dim mes As Object
    Set outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mes = outl.CreateItem(0)
    mes.Display (False)
mes.Close 1

Comment: You're welcome, where it says "Msgbox newinspector" you should put the code that does whatever you want to do when a new message is created.

Comment: did you know a way to get a "moving item" event (move email like from inbox to MyPriorityFolder)

Comment: Yes, but you should probably open a new question and I or someone else can answer it.

Comment: The problem I have with office 2016/o365 is that the code is also fired if I open an existing item not only when I create a new one. Any idea how to thix?