# run a macro when creating new appointment in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm new to outlook vba.

I'd like to run a macro when I create a new appointment in mycalendar in Outlook 2016 32bit

I tried with

```
Private WithEvents appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Private Sub appt_Write(Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox ("test ok")
End Sub
```

in the ThisOutlookSession module but nothing happens when I edit anda save a new appointment.

What I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

You `apt` variable is never initialized and remains null. Try to use `Application.Inspectors.MewInspector` event to check when a new appointment is opened and set apt to `Inspector.CurrentItem` after checking that it is really an appointment. Note that you can have more than one appointment open, so a single apt variable won't work, you need to have a list or array.

Answer (score 2):

From [outlook event newMail (newItem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996292/outlook-event-newmail-newitem)

```
Private WithEvents appt As AppointmentItem
Private WithEvents objinspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objinspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub objinspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If TypeName(Inspector.currentItem) = "AppointmentItem" Then
        MsgBox "newinspector"
        Set appt = Inspector.currentItem    ' <----
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub appt_Write(Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox ("test ok")
End Sub
```

appt will be the most recently opened appointment item

Comment: There's a problem: the macro works just once. If I add a second appointment nothing happen unless i run Application_Startup again. WHY?