# NewInspector event works once only

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code in ThisOutlookSession module from [run a macro when creating new appointment in outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027860/run-a-macro-when-creating-new-appointment-in-outlook):

```vb
Private WithEvents appt As AppointmentItem
Private WithEvents objinspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objinspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub objinspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If TypeName(Inspector.CurrentItem) = "AppointmentItem" Then
        Set appt = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub appt_Write(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    '---- ect
end sub
```

appt_Write works for the first appointment I create or modify. If I create a second appointment nothing happens.

I found the sub objinspectors_NewInspector does not start anymore.

I have no `END` command in my code. To run the code again I have to launch Application_Startup.

What should I do to make the macro work all time?

Answer (score 0):

rerun same code as Application_Startup() each time through

```
Private Sub appt_Write(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    '---- etc

    Set objinspectors = Application.Inspectors 'add this line ... see what happens
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to explain your answer so it is useful to future readers.