Automatically run macro when editing email
We use software from where we can send an email. When we use this button, it uses a mailto: link to start sending an email with the recipient, subject, and body in the mailto: link.
After this email is there, we have to run a macro that adds the right signature.
The subject is always the same. I would very much like the macro to automatically run after the mailto link is pressed and the email editor opens. Is this possible, for instance based on the subject sinds that is always the same?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7997277/478884 shows how to trap the creation of a new amil in Outlook.
